# how to add selected item from one listBox to another listBox

Tags: c#

i have 16 Items in listBox1 and one button "button1", i need to to be able to move the selected Item from listBox1 to listBox2 when a button is pressed. currently my code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace courseworkmodule
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String workingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\modules.xml");

            Console.WriteLine("BaseURI:" + textReader.BaseURI);
            textReader.Read();

            while (textReader.Read())
            {
                textReader.MoveToElement();

                if (textReader.Name == "Name")
                {

                    textReader.Read();
                    XmlNodeType nType = textReader.NodeType;

                    if (nType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                    {
                        listBoxAllModules.Items.Add(textReader.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            textReader.Close();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxStudentModules.Items.Add(listBoxAllModules.SelectedItem); 
        } 

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBoxAllModules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

where listBoxAllModule is listBox1 and listBoxStudentModule is listBox2
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What is wrong with the code ? Is it throwing some error ?

Comment: Also, when you say "move", do you mean you want to remove the entry selected from listboxallmodules?

Comment: its throwing error on "items" such as "Error: Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items' cannot be used like a method"

Comment: no, i want it to stay in listBoxAllModules, when i pressed button it should also appear in ListboxStudentmodules

Answer (score 1):

You can make it explicit to see what is going on:

```
 string value = listBoxAllModules.SelectedItem.Value; 
 string text = listBoxAllModules.SelectedItem.Text;  
 ListItem item = new ListItem (); 
 item.Text = text;                
 item.Value = value;
 listBoxStudentModules.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: i don't want to remove the selected Item from the listBox1, just move it to listBox2 while keeping it in listBox1 as well

Comment: I changed it to not remove anymore.

Comment: done it guys.. i had duplicated button names of button 1 like "button1_Click" and "button1_Click_1" i was suppose the add the code to the latter one. not the first one. appreciatte your help though

Answer (score 1):

`listBoxAllModules.Items` is a [`ListBox.ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx).  You are trying to use it as a method:

listBoxAllModules.**Items(** listBoxAllModules.SelectedItem **)**

This will not work.  You are missing the `Add` call.  Should be `.Items.Add()`.  You should be able to just add the `SelectedItem` as TechnologRich shows:

```
listBoxStudentModules.Items.Add(listBoxAllModules.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: That's why i have .ToString() at the end. And it works via Microsoft website.

Comment: string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: Realistically you dont need that.  `ObjectCollection.Items.Add` takes an `Object` and `SelectedItem` is an `Object`.

Comment: can you check if i m putting the method of button1_Click on the right place -updating my code-

Comment: done it guys.. i had duplicated button names of button 1 like "button1_Click" and "button1_Click_1" i was suppose the add the code to the latter one. not the first one. appreciatte your help though

Comment: Just used this method in my code, thank you very much, works well, +1