# Move item from one listBox to another listBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I need to move items from one ListBox to another. Adding them to the second one works but I want to move multiple selected items.

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox2.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       listBox3.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItem);
       listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

My problem is this moves items one by one, but I need to move multiple selected items in one click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            while (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No item selected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Arthi i found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951977/how-to-add-selected-item-from-one-listbox-to-another-listbox/33280951#33280951